# Bash script to watch execution time of other scripts

Tags: bash

I have a main script which run all the scripts in a folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
for each in /some_folder/*.sh
do
  bash $each
done;
```

I want to know if execution of one of them lasts too long (more than N seconds). For example execution of script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 10000 google.com
```

will lasts very long, and I want my main script to e-mail me after N second.

All I can do now is to run all scripts with `#timeout N` option but it stops them!
Is it possible to E-mail me and not to stop execution of script?

Comment: Is it a problem to run them all in parallel (load wise etc.)? 'cause you could just run them in the background simultaneously, and check up on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
( sleep 10 ; echo 'Takes a while' | sendmail myself@example.com ) &
email_pid=$!
bash $each
kill $email_pid
```

The first command is run in a subshell in the background. It first sleeps a while, then sends email. If the script `$each` finishes before the sleep expires, the subshell is killed without sending email.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

# max seconds before mail alert
MAX_SECONDS=3600

# running the command in the background and get the pid
command_that_takes_a_long_time & _pid=$!

sleep $MAX_SECONDS

# if the pid is alive...
if kill &>/dev/null -0 $_pid; then
    mail -s "script $0 takes more than $MAX_SECONDS" user@domain.tld < /dev/null
fi
```

We run the command in the background, then sleep for MAX_SECONDS in // and alert by email if the process takes more than what is permitted.

Finally, with your specific requirements :

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_SECONDS=3600

alerter(){
    bash "$1" & _pid=$!
    sleep $MAX_SECONDS
    if kill &>/dev/null -0 $_pid; then
        mail -s "$2 takes more than $MAX_SECONDS" user@domain.tld < /dev/null
    fi
}

for each in /some_folder/*.sh; do
    alerter "$each" &
    wait $_pid # remove this line if you wou'd like to run all scripts in //
done
```

Comment: Doesn't this kill the running script, contrary to what the OP asked?

Comment: sorry, `-0` forgotten (just to test if the pid is still alive, that don't kill it)